# How can I invoke the default assignment operator within my own assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, assignment-operator

A very simplified version of my code is as follows:

```
class bCls {
    private:
        /// Many members, not shown for simplicity.
    public:
        /// Custom assignment operator; I would like to use the default operator within.
        bCls& operator=(bCls&& rhs) {
            defaultoperator=(rhs);
            someCustomOperations();
            return *this;
        }
};
```

Is there an elegant solution to use the default assignment operator in place of defaultoperator=(bCls&&)? I wouldn't like to resort to an auxiliary or base class for bCls, and obviously I wouldn't like to make the assignment member by member. Are base or nested classes the only possible solutions? I'm hoping for a solution that keeps the code readable.

Comment: Maybe you could use `nested class` instead according to your need.

Comment: nested class and base class are very similar solutions; thanks for your interest anyway.

Comment: You could forward a non-default move-assignment-operator with a `&` ref qualifier to a (private) default move-assignment operator with a `&&` qualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward *one* of them to the other:

```
A& operator=( const A& ) = default;
A& operator=( A&& a )
{
    std::cout << "=1" << std::endl;
    *this = a;
    std::cout << "=2" << std::endl;
    return a;
}
```

You can not use the same signature as both your own implementation and a second, default generated implementation of the *same* method can not coexist.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb0a42db990207df)

Answer (score 0):

You can also store your data members in a `std::tuple`, and use the tuple's `operator=`. I'm not sure I'd call this a superior solution to the base class, though.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, however I'm hoping for a solution that keeps the code readable.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean `*this ::operator=(rhs);`?

Comment: Nope, this does not call the default assignment operator; this only calls the custom operator again and produces an infinite recursion. Thanks for your interest anyway.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. The `::` should prevent it.

Comment: @arulmr I disagree completely. It's couched as a question, but it contains a possible answer.

Comment: Of course it does, but then Daniel gave a superior answer to mine.

Comment: @EJP: No, it wouldn't. The default operator *simply does not exist*- therefore you cannot call it.

Comment: @DeadMG You are mistaken. Certainly it exists. *qualified-id:* `::` *operator-function-id,* *operator-function-id:* operator *operator,* and *operator:* `+` among others. Source: International Standard ISO/IEC 14882, Programming Languages - C++.